# Is `letter` native to python?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def show_letters(word):
    for letter in word:
        print(letter)

show_letters("Hello")
```

I'm not sure what to call `letter` (object?), but the object was not defined. Is `letter` native to python? And what other native (objects?) are there that I should look out for?

Comment: `letter` is not a builtin in python, no. Also, when I ran the code you gave here, it printed each letter of `Hello` as you'd expect.

Comment: Yes that is correct for the code. How does python know to take each letter from the word provided?

Comment: It's iterating through the string `word`, the name `letter` doesn't matter for it getting each letter.

Comment: `letter` is a variable. You can name it whatever makes the most sense for your code, for example, `for letter in word:`, `for apple in basket:`, and so on.